# Docker Image history without using docker history command

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I have a docker image. I want to analyze the docker image history, for this I can use `docker image history` command in the docker installed environment.

But when am working in a Openshift cluster, I may not have the access to the `docker` command here. So here I want get the `docker history` command result for the given image.

So basically I have a docker image and I don't have docker installed there. In this case how can we get the history of that docker image?

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the registry info either via curl or `skopeo inspect`. But the rest of the metadata is stored inside the image itself so you do have to download at least the final layer.

Comment: I have the image on the linux box. I meant i have downloaded already.

Comment: Inside each unpacked layer directory is a file named `json` with the metadata for that layer.